# Get a list of available printers (Wifi, bluetooth, USBs) and print the document using the selected printer

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a list of available printers (Wifi, bluetooth, USBs) and print the document using the selected printer. A few posts suggest using PrinterDiscoverySession to get the list of printers, but I couldn't find a suitable example for the same.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with you. If you have any solution, please provide for me.

Answer (score 1):

excuse me . i cant writing English good .

if you have pdf document you can use this code for all print :

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) Pdf_activity.this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);


        String jobName = "testpdf";

        PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter()
        {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback)
            {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    File file = new 
      File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null),"factore.pdf"); //direction your document 
                    input = new FileInputStream(file);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)
            {
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled())
                {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                    return;
                }

                //int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);

                PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Factore.pdf").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();
                callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);

            }
        };
        printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
    }
```

this work for me good.

but if you print from your view first create pdf from your view ,
I also have those codes . 
If you want to tell me to send you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I want to display the list of available printers. Please provide some code for that.

Comment: Yes, this code does exactly that. Displays all available printers, even pdf

Comment: This is the default print mechanism. I need to create a custom screen that would get all the printers, categorize them in Wifi, Bluetooth, USB categories and then print the invoice from selected printer. For future use this printer should be selected automatically.