# Can someone provide an example of how to use the PrintDiscoverySession class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, printing, network-programming

I am a student learning to develop an android app. Can someone help me with an example of how to use the PrintDiscoverySession class in Android Studio to find a list of printers on the network? This is a similar request to the link below.

[Get a list of available printers (Wifi, bluetooth, USBs) and print the document using the selected printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956104/get-a-list-of-available-printers-wifi-bluetooth-usbs-and-print-the-document)